# Falha ao conectar ao SQL server com nodeJs (Sequelize)

Tags: sql-server, node.js, sequelize-js

Estou desenvolvendo um CRUD com nodejs mas estou com problemas ao conectar ao SQL server.

*Classe responsável por fazer a conexão:*

```
const sequelize = require('sequelize');

const database = new sequelize('master', 'sa', '1#kaLvX91', {
    
    dialect: 'mssql', host:'localhost', port:1433
});

database.sync();

module.exports = database;
});

database.sync();

module.exports = database;
```

*O erro que estou recebendo:*

```
\connection-manager.js:109
          throw new sequelizeErrors.ConnectionError(error);
                ^

ConnectionError [SequelizeConnectionError]: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - Could not connect (sequence)
    at ConnectionManager.connect (C:\Users\raf_r\OneDrive\Nodejs\CRUD\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mssql\connection-manager.js:109:17)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async ConnectionManager._connect (C:\Users\raf_r\OneDrive\Nodejs\CRUD\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:220:24)
    at async C:\Users\raf_r\OneDrive\Nodejs\CRUD\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:174:32
    at async ConnectionManager.getConnection (C:\Users\raf_r\OneDrive\Nodejs\CRUD\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:197:7)
    at async C:\Users\raf_r\OneDrive\Nodejs\CRUD\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:301:26
    at async MSSqlQueryInterface.tableExists (C:\Users\raf_r\OneDrive\Nodejs\CRUD\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-interface.js:102:17)
    at async Function.sync (C:\Users\raf_r\OneDrive\Nodejs\CRUD\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:939:21)
    at async Sequelize.sync (C:\Users\raf_r\OneDrive\Nodejs\CRUD\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:373:9) {
  parent: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - Could not connect (sequence)
      at Connection.socketError (C:\Users\raf_r\OneDrive\Nodejs\CRUD\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1425:28)
      at C:\Users\raf_r\OneDrive\Nodejs\CRUD\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1185:21
      at SequentialConnectionStrategy.connect (C:\Users\raf_r\OneDrive\Nodejs\CRUD\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:129:14)
      at Socket.onError (C:\Users\raf_r\OneDrive\Nodejs\CRUD\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:149:12)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
      at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
      at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
    code: 'ESOCKET',
    isTransient: undefined
  },
  original: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - Could not connect (sequence)
      at Connection.socketError (C:\Users\raf_r\OneDrive\Nodejs\CRUD\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1425:28)
      at C:\Users\raf_r\OneDrive\Nodejs\CRUD\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1185:21
      at SequentialConnectionStrategy.connect (C:\Users\raf_r\OneDrive\Nodejs\CRUD\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:129:14)
      at Socket.onError (C:\Users\raf_r\OneDrive\Nodejs\CRUD\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:149:12)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
      at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
      at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
    code: 'ESOCKET',
    isTransient: undefined
  }
}
```

Comment: As opções passadas como parâmetro não parecem estar corretas, veja https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/dialect-specific-things/#mssql . O sequelize utiliza o pacote tedious como conector MSSQL e esse precisa de opções próprias.

Answer (score -3):

Primeiro você precisa remover o "database.sync()" e o "module.exports" repetidos do seu código, deixar apenas umas vez. E instala o pacote 'tedious' necessário pra conexão com o mssql. Pra instalar: `npm install tedious`

Sugiro tu dá uma lida no artigo abaixo que me ajudou bastante a entender: [Node.js + MSSQL](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2022/06/20/nodejs-mssql-connect-to-sql-server-with-sequelize-tedious)